# Не получается сохранить и вернуть данные с localStorage! Help?

Tags: html, jquery, localstorage

Суть такая когда пользователь удаляет картинки, сохраняем данные о том, что было удалено, и после перезагрузки страницы удалённые ранее картинки должны отсутствовать на странице.
Внизу кнопка "Восстановить", которая делает все скрытые пользователем картинки видимыми.
Как удалить а потом вернуть их я сделал, а вот как сделать чтоб после перезагрузки страницы удаленные ранее картинки отсутствовали не получается.
Как сохранить в localStorage что удалено и что осталось?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var serialreal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyReal'));
  var serialdel = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('keyDel'));

  $('.block>.img').on('click', '.delete', function() {
    space = $(this).parent('.img').detach();
    $(space).prependTo('.box'); //переносим для времменого хранения.

    var del; //что удалилось
    del = $('.box > div');
    var real; //что осталося
    real = $('.block>.img');

    var serialdel = JSON.stringify(del);
    localStorage.setItem('keyDel', serialdel);

    var serialreal = JSON.stringify(real);
    localStorage.setItem('keyReal', serialreal);
  });
  $('.restore').click(function() {
    $('.img').prependTo('.block');
  });
});
```

```css
.img {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

.restore {
  width: 60px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.delete {
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  right: -25px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="img">
    <div class="delete">X</div>
    <img src="https://www.purecabo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Cabo-CruiseShip-Schedule.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <div class="delete">X</div>
    <img src="http://www.shipspotting.com/photos/middle/2/9/9/1498992.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="restore">вернуть</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: `src` картинки сохраняйте, а не дивы целиком

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sashakou/68shmxq3/ наверное я что-то делаю не так

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с подобной проблемой при написании огромного UserScript-плагина, так как не было доступа к Backend-части сайта.

> Как сохранить в localStorage что удалено и что осталось?

Для себя решил проблему созданием объектов, которые хранили данные о нужных элементах (в данном случае данные о состоянии картинки). Абстрактно:

```
function ElementState(key, boolean) {
    return key = {
        isDeleted: boolean
    }
}

let yourImgState = JSON.stringify(new ElementState(key, boolean));
```

Эти объекты записывались в LocalStorage. По нажатию на кнопку удаления - состояние перезаписывается в виде пары ключ значение:

```
key: { isDeleted: true }
```

Схема такая: при загрузке страницы выполняем проверку соответствия текущего состояния элемента (его видимости) с состоянием, которое хранится в LocalStorage:

1. Если элемент по-умолчанию видимый, а в LocalStorage для данного элемента установлена пара:

   ```
   key: { isDeleted: true },
   ```

то элемент изменяет свою видимость при отрисовке страницы.

2. Если в состоянии прописана пара:

   ```
   key: { isDeleted: false },
   ```

   то ничего не меняется.